# Is it better to load the whole firebase into a variable or just separate specific objects?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm learning angularfire and i wonder if i need the whole data from my database (but i want to perform CRUD operations on each "entity") is it better to do this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
var db = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

db.$loaded(function (db) {
    console.log('loaded db is', db);
    $scope.categories = db.categories;
    $scope.products = db.products;
});
```

or

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
var products = $firebase(ref.child('products')).$asArray();
var categories = $firebase(ref.child('categories')).$asArray();

products.$loaded(function (loadedProducts) {
     console.log('loaded products are', loadedProducts);
     $scope.products = loadedProducts;
});

products.$loaded(function (loadedCategories) {
     console.log('loaded categories are', loadedCategories);
     $scope.categories = loadedCategories;
});
```

Also what is a good approach if i want a sidebar with a list of my categories with every product in the category? How should i join my data? In every category i'm storing a list of products with ids like

```
category:{
     name:"Machines"
     products:[alskdjgasld,asldkgjb2k2349,eoilfkasdbf2,21iyebfhsdafas]
}
```

Then when i want to display the category with the products in my html, what is the best way to join them and to keep them in sync? I mean if the product name changes the change should be reflected in the joined list too, automatically. What is the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about "the best way" typically lead to opinionated answers. The best way is whatever works for all of your use-cases, which we can't know. It's often better to show what you tried and tell us why you're not satisfied with the result.

Comment: If your Firebase database only contains products and categories, then the first two code-snippets will give the same performance. I personally prefer the second snippet, because it is a more explicit mapping. But if someone prefers the former, they are in the right too.

Comment: Please open a separate question for the bit about joins. In that question please include a sample of your JSON data, some of the code showing what you've already tried and why you're not satisfied with that code or the results you're getting from it.